# Lock Android App in Landscape mode using Android SDK 30

Tags: android, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0, sdl-2, landscape

For previous versions of the SDK these lines in the AndroidManifest.xml file were enough to avoid orientation changes and activity resets:

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|orientation|fontScale|orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation"
```

Now I'm using Android Studio V 4.1.1.

Android SDK 30.

Android NDK 21.1.6352462. NDK APP_PLATFORM: 16.

Android Gradle Plugin V 4.1.1 and Gradle Version 6.5.

SDL V2.0.12.

OpenGL ES 2.0.

And I am unable to prevent a layout change when rotating into portrait mode. The screen always splits in half and cuts the extra portion of the image to the right.

Is there anything else that must be considered now?

Aside from that I am aware that to achieve the fullscreen immersive mode some changes must be done since the flags normally used for it are deprecated for SDK 30. Example : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN

The SDL Activity handled that for previous versions overriding the Handler method and setting the flags:

```
Window window = ((Activity) context).getWindow();
                    if (window != null) {
                        if ((msg.obj instanceof Integer) && (((Integer) msg.obj).intValue() != 0)) {
                            int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY |
                                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN |
                                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.INVISIBLE;
                            window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
                            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
                            SDLActivity.mFullscreenModeActive = true;
                        } else {
                            int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE;
                            window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
                            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
                            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                            SDLActivity.mFullscreenModeActive = false;
                        }
                    }
```

I will add now a proper setup for the SDK 30 using WindowInsetsController options just in case.

Comment: Not sure if you are aware of 'multi-window mode', https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window#configuring

Comment: @MorrisonChang I just tested it as false and it didn't work. I wasn't using multiwindow devices or emulators though.

Comment: There's a developer mode option called 'Force activities to be resizable'. Could you check you haven't enabled that?

Comment: Yes I already checked that @Columbo